# How do I get Firefox debugger watch's target element?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox-addon, watch, firefox-developer-tools

I've been trying to add the highlighting feature to the Firefox DevTools debugger, so it will highlight the element instead of only showing [HTMLAnchorElement] or similar. I know it's possible, since you can set `someElement.style.border='1px solid blue'` or similar as a watch, and it hightlights the element. So why not let it store current border, and show it on mouseover using `element.style.border='1px solid blue'`, and restore it on mouseout?
[image: Cannot inspect where the document of these elements in the watch expressions are.]

While debugging in Firefox devtools, I noticed the element in the right watch panel has rows with the variable names, which are actually given odd ids like "46439", under parent element with "document.getelementsbytagname('a')36" id. What do these ids signify? Can they map a display element to its target element in the page? I tried `window.DebuggerView.WatchExpressions.getItemForElement` from Venkman but it returns null. Is there another function from [this source file](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/34a9d08a82c4/browser/devtools/debugger/debugger-panes.js) that will give the target element of debugger watch?

Ideally, I should be able to 'watch' items such as `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`, or local variable in the debug context, and highlight the items in the page like Chromium/Firebug. Yet I'm not sure how to add this feature from a Firefox extension.

**Update**:

After further work, it would seem to be possible to use the `DebuggerView.StackFrames.evaluate` to run code while stopped at a breakpoint, like what `chrome://browser/content/devtools/debugger-controller.js` is doing with watches. Unfortunately when stopped at a breakpoint I run this code, and `DebuggerView.StackFrames.evaluate` is `[void] void` in Venkman. Is this evaluate command hidden or private somehow, or not initialized?

Comment: Have you checked the development tools in Firefox 25 (Firefox Nightly), this might contain the stuff you want. I also highly recommend you to use FireBug because it has a lot of usefull features, also the one you're searching for.

Comment: @TimVisee Thanks, but I couldn't even get as far as adding a watch like in the screenshot above, in Nightly. Are you saying the highlighter api in robcee's answer is available, or soon to be available in 25?

Comment: @TimVisee Where is that feature in the soon-to-be-released Firefox 25?

Comment: You can use an alpha version if you'd like, you should give Firefox Nightly a try. Make sure you know that this version might be a bit unstable, I personally use it as my main browser and I don't have much problems though. Anyways, you can find a download on this page: http://nightly.mozilla.org/. Once you've downloaded and started Nightly (You can't start nightly and firefox at the same time!) you have to use the firefox menu, then you'll see a developer menu with lots of features included. Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't see the inspected-object's element highlighting in Nightly when I used it recently. How do you activate that?

Comment: I don't fully understand you probably, but I do see a dotted line aroud the object that is being focused. This feature should be enabled by default as far as I know. You might want to take a look on the properties TAB of the developer tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really use the highlighter from the Debugger directly yet. We have a bug open (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653545) to make the highlighter more generally-available to our other tools.

If you have a unique selector, you can use the command line (Shift-F2 to open the Developer Toolbar) to inspect an element via:

```
inspect unique-selector
```

We intend to make DOM objects highlightable everywhere in upcoming versions of the Firefox Developer Tools.

*edit - This feature has been landed and now works from the Variables View and the Console. Landed in March of 2014 in Firefox 30.*

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/03/box-model-highlighter-web-console-improvements-firefox-os-hud-more-firefox-developer-tools-episode-30/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately it doesn't specify a target release - Firefox 25? 26? 27? Is there any object we can currently use to get access to the element a debugger watch points to? This is one major feature that keeps me from using the builtin debugger most of the time.

Comment: Apparently `unique-selector` has to be a jquery-style selector, not an actual variable, and it seems it is limited to one element.

Comment: Until that feature is finished, is there any way one could just get a reference to a watched element in inspector/debugger's listing as shown in my screenshot above?

Comment: This feature has been landed and now works from the Variables View and the Console. Landed in March of 2014 in Firefox 30.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/03/box-model-highlighter-web-console-improvements-firefox-os-hud-more-firefox-developer-tools-episode-30/

Comment: Can you update your answer so I can mark that this is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are putting too much efforts in inbuilt debugger,

to debug javascript you must use fireBug its best tool,

[This Link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) is for the addon of firebug, download and install the add-on its hardly 2 MB and then you will enjoy debugging.. :)

---

Edit: Selector in Debugger

I was searching answer for your specific question, and found out this

[`Web Console Method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)

Now here you are able to debug, get element and get selector details too..
(Refer **Basic Usage**)

You can directly access variables defined on the page:

```
> $ function(selector, context){
   return new jQuery.fn.init(selector,context);
}
```

please refer the above link for more details..

If native console is not available refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript), this says,

Under Microsoft Windows you additionally need to start Firefox via the following command to have a native console :

`firefox.exe -console`

so that will enable firefox to start with console..

Edit: Log
To log the element tested>> refere [this link](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers) in that refer pprint() that will also behave in the same way.

Also [`Console API`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) there refer [`console.log`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log)

I hope this will help..

Comment: Thanks, but I have used Firebug for years, recently it has become really slow, and freezes up the browser completely. I'd like to use the Firefox tool, considering that the built in DevTools are in active development right now, and the inspector tool is already better than Firebug/Chrome in many ways, and it doesn't work as clunky as Firebug (Go to scripts panel, see it's not enabled yet, go to dropdown and click enable, have to refresh the page to use it, for example).

Comment: IN that case check the options of Log, and clear logs.. that will solve the freezing problem.., or else there is one more option with Firebug **Firebug Lite** you can use that too.. :) and to enable all just click the down arrow with firebug icon (in Firefox) top right and enable all you are done with enabling all :)

Comment: Firebug Lite does not even have js debugging. Even if Firebug works, ( I tried it again with 22 and it seems it may be faster) this isn't a complete solution to this problem. Firebug apparently doesn't support remote debugging for example, and Firefox inspector is better in some ways than the Firebug inspector.

Comment: If in that case I have chrome with developer extension(add-on) installed with it and it helps with many things, I am confused with your requirements not, as the question is explaining CSS problems and we are discussing JS debugger :)

Comment: Thanks you, that is also a useful plugin, but I don't think you understand the original question - about inspecting *within* Firefox's debugger. I suppose it wasn't quite clear, for clarity I've added a screenshot.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please refer if it may help.. thank you

Comment: Thanks, but there's two problems still: I heard there were plans for making the web console use the scope of the current debugging script, but I'm pretty sure this is in-progress now. 2) While you can use `$0` to get the currently inspected element, I didn't see a way to set the inspected-element.

Comment: Yes, but there is no way to click it in the console's log, and see where in the page that element was. That's no better than inspecting in the right panel of screenshot.