# Firefox Developer Tools: Highlight element found through queryselector in console as per. 'Inspect Element'

Tags: console, selectors-api, firefox-developer-tools

If I open Firefox Web Develop Web Console and I reference a query selector like this:

```
document.querySelector('selector');
```

I would like to highlight the selector that is returned, in the same style as if I were to right click the element and select 'Inspect Element'

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976238, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has landed.
Now DOMNodes are nicely outputted to the webconsole:

- They are colored like in the inspector
- Hovering over them highlights them in the page
- Clicking on the inspector icon next to them switches over to the inspector

Answer (score 1):

We are due to land that feature but for now you can use shift+f2 to bring up the Firefox command line and type inspect  to do the same thing.